# Jetpack Compose DropDown with generic implementation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-ui

Currently, I have a `DropDown` implemented with particular types. I would like to make that drop-down menu generic so I can reuse it everywhere with custom objects and remove boilerplate code.

**Current Implementation**

```
    @Composable
fun SingleLineDropDown(optionsFieldState: OptionsFieldState<String>, hintText: String, isEditable: Boolean = true) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    var textFieldSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }

    val icon = if (expanded) Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowUp else Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown

    val modifier = if (isEditable) {
        Modifier.clickable { expanded = !expanded }
    } else Modifier

    Box {
        EditableRow(
            value = optionsFieldState.value ?: "",
            onValueChange = { optionsFieldState.value = it },
            enabled = false,
            error = optionsFieldState.error.orEmpty(),
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                    //This value is used to assign to the DropDown the same width
                    textFieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
                },
            hintText = hintText,
            trailingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    icon, null, modifier
                )
            },
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                disabledTextColor = if (isEditable) MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground else Color.LightGray
            )
        )
        if (isEditable) {
            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
                modifier = Modifier.width(with(LocalDensity.current) { textFieldSize.width.toDp() })
            ) {
                optionsFieldState.options.forEach { option ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                        optionsFieldState.value = option
                        expanded = !expanded
                    }) {
                        Text(text = option)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Caller function**

```
SingleLineDropDown(
    optionsFieldState = state.province,
    hintText = stringResource(id = R.string.province_territory),
    isEditable = state.isAddressEditable
)
```

**OptionFiledState** is custom state for compose UI

```
open class OptionsFieldState<T>(
    initialValue: T?,
    options: List<T> = listOf(),
    validators: List<Validator> = listOf(),
    onValueChanged: () -> Unit = {},
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your drop-down menu to be applicable to generics custom objects, you can change your `SingleLineDropDown` function with generics, along side one extra parameters for the function to make it work

Follow this example to understand how it can be done:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun <T> SingleLineDropDown(
    optionsFieldState: OptionsFieldState<T>,
    hintText: String,
    isEditable: Boolean = true,
    displayText: @Composable (T) -> Unit // Composable function to display the selected option
) {
    // Rest of your code...

    Box {
        EditableRow(
            // Rest of your code...
        )
        if (isEditable) {
            DropdownMenu(
                // Rest of your code...
            ) {
                optionsFieldState.options.forEach { option ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                        optionsFieldState.value = option
                        expanded = !expanded
                    }) {
                        displayText(option) // Call the displayText function to show the selected option
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it the following way:

```kotlin
SingleLineDropDown(
    optionsFieldState = state.province,
    hintText = stringResource(id = R.string.province_territory),
    isEditable = state.isAddressEditable
) { option ->
    // Customize how the selected option is displayed
    Text(text = option.name) // Assuming the custom object has a "name" property
}
```

**Update**
You can also provide a default value for the generic to be used in the `EditableRow`, something like that:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun <T> SingleLineDropDown(
    optionsFieldState: OptionsFieldState<T>,
    hintText: String,
    isEditable: Boolean = true,
    displayText: @Composable (T) -> Unit,
    defaultOptionValue : T
) {
    // Rest of your code...

    Box {
        EditableRow(
            value = optionsFieldState.value ?: defaultOptionValue,
            onValueChange = { optionsFieldState.value = it },
            enabled = false,
            error = optionsFieldState.error.orEmpty(),
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                    //This value is used to assign to the DropDown the same width
                    textFieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
                },
            hintText = hintText,
            trailingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    icon, null, modifier
                )
            },
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                disabledTextColor = if (isEditable) MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground else Color.LightGray
            )
        )
       // Rest of your code...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I also have some logic in `EditableRow` to set that custom object in `OptionFieldState` if you can provide that as well would be great help.

Comment: I am not able to know what is `optionFieldState.error`  and `optionFieldState.value`, and I think it is the same thing as the previous ones, maybe just add some default value to the EditableRow when passing the data!

Comment: Just updated the code; kindly check.